# prints it with a space at the beginning and end vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that converts from excel to notepad. The problem I have is that it currently prints it with a space at the beginning and end.

code:

```
    Print #1, "<ROWdtfield QTY="; """"; Cells(i, 3).Value; """"
```

prints:<ROWdtfield QTY=" 7506192505543 "
I need:<ROWdtfield QTY="7506192505543".

If I remove or add quotes, the macro does not run.

Could you help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use concatenation instead of semi-colons.

```
Print #1, "<ROWdtfield QTY=""" & Cells(i, 3).Value & """"
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't make yourself crazy trying to figure out when to double-quote, when to triple quote, or when to add four, or even six quotes (!!!) - well, you can do so for fun. But when you have work to do I recommend just using simple `chr()` functions.

```
Print #1, "<ROWdtfield QTY=" & Chr(34) & Cells(i, 3).Value & Chr(34)
```

Note: I agree with @StoneGiant that using semi-colons here seems to be out of place - just use regular string concatenation as there seems no reason to be trying to manipulate tab settings, insertion points, etc. in this [print statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/printstatement).

Answer (score 0):

An option I can think of is to use assign the string to a variable and then perform a tRIM on the variable.

```vb
Dim strText As String
strText = "   Hello World   "
strText = TRIM(strText)
```